# How to turn SOME server online during agent plug SILENTLY?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, gnus

I would like to turn on **SOME** server when turning gnus agent into online status **BUT** without asking user any questions.

I have integrated `Network Manager` support into emacs/gnus. It changes gnus agent online/offline state automatically.  I want no question being asked during offline to online switch.

I use emacs24.

Comment: I suggest you submit your integration of Network Manager to the Gnus guys, since they may be interested in that feature, and at the same time, ask them how to further improve your patch so that some server get re-started automatically without question.

Comment: @Stefan I have tested (slightly modified) nm integration recipe from EmacsWiki.org.  I would prefer "on demand" connections instead of forcing connections.  Anyway I have achieved "tolerable" configuration. It requires manual switching one nntp server to "open state" once after emacs/gnus startup.